# Выдает ошубку на 3 строчке: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')' вроде все нормально написано

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(isset($_POST['add_to_card'])){
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){

        $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], column: "product_id")




        print_r($item_array_id);

    }else{
        $item_array = array(
            'product_id' => $_POST['product_id']
        );
        $_SESSION['cart']['0'] = $item_array;
        print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
    }

    
}
```

Comment: А где вы такую запись видели вообще? `array_column($_SESSION['cart'], column: "product_id")`

Comment: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAK8uYtNTy4&t=2616s&ab_channel=DailyTuition) 47:43

Comment: Так это PHPShtorm подставляет названия переменных функции, чтобы было понятно. В синтаксисе PHP это ошибка передавать что-то как `название: значение`. И да, точка с запятой в конце строки.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю это синтаксис PHP 8, но для начала исправьте строчку дописав символ «;»:

```
$item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], column: "product_id");
```

Comment: Нет, это не синтаксис PHP в прицнипе

Comment: Спасибо, решил вопрос просто удалив column

Comment: @VladimirGonchar В версии php8 это возможно)
Скриншот:  https://prnt.sc/173hfpk
Документация:  https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php

Comment: @AhmadAkhmadaliev Отлично)